# MemoryCache Contains() thread-safety

Tags: c#, caching, concurrency, thread-safety

`MemoryCache` is a thread-safe class, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) article. But I don't understand how it will behave in a specific situation. For example I have the code:

```
static private MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

...

if (_cache.Contains("Test"))
{
    return _cache.Get("Test") as string;
}
```

1. Can element's living time expire just after I call `Contains()` so `null` value will be returned?
2. Can another thread remove item just after I call `Contains()` so `null` value will be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes, these are common race conditions. You can avoid them if by simply writing the code as

```
var test = _cache.Get("Test");
if (test != null) {
    return test as string;
}
```

Comment: And if I want to write new value in expired item I just use `else { string result = 'some data from my database'; _cache.Set("Test", result, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30)); return result; }` and everything will be ok. Is it right?

Comment: @ChruS: No, in that case to avoid race conditions you should use [`AddOrGetExisting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780587.aspx) instead.